# VS Code C/C++ extension intellisense can't detect environment specific functions

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gcc, intellisense

When I'm writing C codes on VS Code, IntelliSense can't detect functions declared in standard libraries, while the project compile properly.

Details:

The `flockfile` function is declared as `void flockfile (FILE *__stream)` in `stdio.h`, however IntelliSense treats the function wrongly.

[image]

I found the [information](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/828#issuecomment-308592066) that old C compilers treat undeclared functions as `int functionname()`.
So I guess that intellisense thinks that `flockfile` hasn't been declared yet, even though I certainly include `stdio.h` at the top of the file which uses `flockfile`.

When I opened `stdio.h` on VS Code, the definition of `fnlockfile` is displayed as the unreachable code.

[image]

However, the project compile properly without warnings related to `fnlockfile` and the built app also works properly.
So I think the root cause of this problem is that the compiler used by IntelliSense receives different arguments from ones the actual compiler receives.

How can I make IntelliSense interpret codes as well as the actual compiler does?

I searched around the related reports on the internet, but I wasn't able to find.
Adding `__USE_POSIX199506` definition before including `stdio.h` might address the issue, but I'm using `stdio.h` in a couple of files and I don't want to write that definition every time I include `stdio.h`.

Environment:

Host OS: Windows10
Guest OS: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (WSL2)
Compiler: gcc version 11.4.0 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04)
Editor: VS Code(1.87.2) with C/C++ extension from Microsoft (v1.19.9)

`.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json` file;

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64",
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cpptools"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

`which gcc` answers `/usr/bin/gcc`

I'm not savvy in compiler around things, so sorry if it was a silly question...

---

Edit (add minimap reproducible example)

1. Create a new project folder.
2. Create main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    flockfile(stderr);
    fprintf(stderr, "hello world\n");
    funlockfile(stderr);
    return 0;
}
```

3. Create `.vscode` folder and put the above `c_cpp_properties.json`.
4. Run below commands to build and run an executable.

```
$ cc -g -W -Wall -Wno-unused-parameter -iquote . -pthread -iquote platform/linux -c main.c -o main.o
$ cc -g -W -Wall -Wno-unused-parameter -o out.a main.o
$ ./out.a
hello world
```

4. However, IntelliSense in VS Code can't detect `flockfile` properly.

[image]

Comment: From my experience, Clangd (an alternative intellisense plugin) is better at those things.

Comment: you could put that thing in your c_cpp_properties configuration's `defines` array. that would solve the intellisense issue. but I'm curious why intellisense is different than what you get from compilation. please show the flags you use for compilation ([mre]). also, related docs are in https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html

Comment: Thank you HolyBlackCat! Actually, I encountered this error when I tried to use clang-tidy.
clang-tidy gave me error squiggle under `fnlockfile` calling.
So I first thought that was clang-tidy problem, but I end up finding that this problem is produced even if I turned clang-tidy off.

Comment: Thank you too starball.
My compile command is `cc  -g -W -Wall -Wno-unused-parameter -iquote . -pthread -iquote platform/linux -c (source file path) -o (object file path)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the C/C++ extension (cpptools) (and many other C/C++ extensions for VS Code), intellisense is separate from build. See [the related official FAQ entry](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/faq-cpp#_how-do-i-get-intellisense-to-work-correctly). You either need to manually configure the VS Code extension providing intellisense to know how exactly you are doing build, or find an extension that does both, or one that integrates build info to the C/C++ extension, [such as the CMake extension](/a/77079021/11107541).

In this specific case, you were passing `-pthread` during build, but not to the C/C++ extension for intellisense.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the problem was solved.

I realized that the compiler args which I passed to the actual compiler wasn't told to intellisense.

So I added `compilerArgs` parameter to `c_cpp_properties.json`

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "compilerArgs": ["-g", "-W", "-Wall", "-Wno-unused-parameter", "-iquote", ".", "-pthread", "-iquote", "platform/linux"], # added this line
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64",
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cpptools"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Then, intellisense can detenct `flockfile` properly.

Thank you for everyone who gave me comments.

[image]

Comment: curious. what's the minimum set of flags you need to put there for intellisense to know about flockfile?

Comment: If I gave `-pthread` only, it still knew `flockfile`.

If I deleted `-pthread` from the set of options above, it couldn't detect `flockfile`.

So, I think `-pthread` is the key flag here.